# Replace specific rows with NA values from another data.frame

Tags: r, replace, na

Y have 2 dataframes with the same number of columns and rows. I need replace NA values in specific rows of dfA with values in same rows from dfB. For example:

**dfA**

| X | Y | Z |
| --- | --- | --- |
| NA | NA | NA |
| 74 | 42 | 18 |
| NA | NA | NA |
| NA | NA | NA |

**dfB**

| X | Y | Z |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 250 | 456 | 258 |
| 145 | 745 | 251 |
| 236 | 257 | 159 |
| 753 | 852 | 456 |

I tried

```py
dfA[c(1,3,4),] <-replace(dfA[c(1,3,4),], is.na(dfA[c(1,3,4),]), dfA[c(1,3,4),])
```

the expected result should be
**dfA**

| X | Y | Z |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 250 | 456 | 258 |
| 74 | 42 | 18 |
| 236 | 257 | 159 |
| 753 | 852 | 456 |

but I get

**dfA**

| X | Y | Z |
| --- | --- | --- |
| c(250,456,258) | c(250,456,258) | c(250,456,258) |
| 74 | 42 | 18 |
| c(236,257,159) | c(236,257,159) | c(236,257,159) |
| c(753,852,456) | c(753,852,456) | c(753,852,456) |

Thanks for your valuable help!

Answer (score 1):

If you have specified the rows for the replacement, you can try

```
> dfA[c(1, 3, 4), ] <- dfB[c(1, 3, 4), ]

> dfA
    X   Y   Z
1 250 456 258
2  74  42  18
3 236 257 159
4 753 852 456
```

---

If you want to replace all `NA` by values from `dfB`, with base R, you can try

```
> list2DF(Map(\(a, b) ifelse(is.na(a), b, a), dfA, dfB))
    X   Y   Z
1 250 456 258
2  74  42  18
3 236 257 159
4 753 852 456
```

or

```
> replace(dfA, is.na(dfA), dfB[is.na(dfA)])
    X   Y   Z
1 250 456 258
2  74  42  18
3 236 257 159
4 753 852 456
```

## data

```
> dput(dfA)
structure(list(X = c(NA, 74L, NA, NA), Y = c(NA, 42L, NA, NA),
    Z = c(NA, 18L, NA, NA)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA,
-4L))

> dput(dfB)
structure(list(X = c(250L, 145L, 236L, 753L), Y = c(456L, 745L,
257L, 852L), Z = c(258L, 251L, 159L, 456L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA,
-4L))
```

Comment: @RitchieSacramento thanks a lot! I almost forgot that nice property